# building a product edit page using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apart of my finals project is to build a product edit page in PHP. The problem is my instructor stopped teaching PDO early on as one of the students claimed their webserver did not support it. So I have had to teach myself PDO and my instructor gradually started placing PDO versions of the code in the class website. The problem is he never did on based on the product edit page and I am at a stand still. He had suggested I use bindParam() in place of what I was doing, but it did not help. I have been stuck in this one spot for sometime and most of the website is finished with the exception of a couple of pages. here is the code from my product edit page, and as always, thank you for any help that can be provided.

```
<?php
    $page_title = 'Product Edit';
    require '../inc/header.php';
?>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $query = "
            UPDATE fin_prod(
                prod_model,
                prod_desc,
                prod_price,
                prod_vol,
                prod_img1,
                prod_img1_desc,
                prod_img2,
                prod_img2_desc,
                prod_img3,
                prod_img3_desc,
                prod_img4,
                prod_img4_desc,
                prod_img5,
                prod_img5_desc,
                prod_ulvl,
                prod_cat,
                prod_type,
                prod_manu,
                prod_view,
                prod_imaging,
                prod_op_design,
                prod_focal_length,
                prod_op_dia,
                prod_focal_ratio,
                prod_op_type,
                prod_glass,
                prod_eye1,
                prod_eye1_mag,
                prod_eye2,
                prod_eye2_mag,
                prod_low_mag,
                prod_high_mag,
                prod_theo_mag,
                prod_lim_stel,
                prod_op_qual,
                prod_finder,
                prod_focus,
                prod_sec_obs,
                prod_sec_obs_dia,
                prod_sec_obs_area,
                prod_coat,
                prod_mount_type,
                prod_astro_img,
                prod_comp,
                prod_mat_bear,
                prod_mat_mount,
                prod_tube_len,
                prod_weight_tube,
                prod_weight_mnt,
                prod_feat,
                prod_warranty
            ) VALUES(
                :prodmodel,
                :proddesc,
                :prodprice,
                :prodvol,
                :prodimg1,
                :prodimg1_desc,
                :prodimg2,
                :prodimg2_desc,
                :prodimg3,
                :prodimg3_desc,
                :prodimg4,
                :prodimg4_desc,
                :prodimg5,
                :prodimg5_desc,
                :prodlvl,
                :prodcat,
                :prodtype,
                :prodmanu,
                :prodview,
                :prodimaging,
                :prod_opdesign,
                :prod_focallen,
                :prod_opdia,
                :prod_focalratio,
                :prod_optype,
                :prodglass,
                :prodeye1,
                :prodeye1_mag,
                :prodeye2,
                :prodeye2_mag,
                :prod_maglow,
                :prod_maghigh,
                :prod_magtheo,
                :prod_limstel,
                :prod_opqual,
                :prodfinder,
                :prodfocus,
                :prod_secobs,
                :prod_secobs_dia,
                :prod_secobs_area,
                :prodcoat,
                :prodmnt_type,
                :prodastro,
                :prodcomp,
                :prodmat_bear,
                :prodmat_mount,
                :prodtube_len,
                :prodweight_tube,
                :prodweight_mnt,
                :prodfeat,
                :prodwarranty
            )
        ";

        /*$queryparams = array(
            ':prodmodel' => $prod_model,
            ':proddesc' => $prod_desc,
            ':prodprice' => $prod_price,
            ':prodvol' => $prod_vol,
            ':prodimg1' => $prod_img1,
            ':prodimg1_desc' => $prod_img1_desc,
            ':prodimg2' => $prod_img2,
            ':prodimg2_desc' => $prod_img2_desc,
            ':prodimg3' => $prod_img3,
            ':prodimg3_desc' => $prod_img3_desc,
            ':prodimg4' => $prod_img4,
            ':prodimg4_desc' => $prod_img4_desc,
            ':prodimg5' => $prod_img5,
            ':prodimg5_desc' => $prod_img5_desc,
            ':prodlvl' => $prod_ulvl,
            ':prodtype' => $prod_type,
            ':prodmanu' => $prod_manu,
            ':prodview' => $prod_view,
            ':prodimaging' => $prod_imaging,
            ':prod_opdesign' => $prod_op_design,
            ':prod_focallen' => $prod_focal_len,
            ':prod_opdia' => $prod_op_dia,
            ':prod_focalratio' => $prod_focal_ratio,
            ':prod_optype' => $prod_op_type,
            ':prodglass' => $prod_glass,
            ':prodeye1' => $prod_eye1,
            ':prodeye1_mag' => $prod_eye1_mag,
            ':prodeye2' => $prod_eye2,
            ':prodeye2_mag' => $prod_eye2_mag,
            ':prod_maglow' => $prod_mag_low,
            ':prod_maghigh' => $prod_mag_high,
            ':prod_magtheo' => $prod_mag_theo,
            ':prod_limstel' => $prod_lim_stel,
            ':prod_opqual' => $prod_op_qual,
            ':prodfinder' => $prod_finder,
            ':prodfocus' => $prod_focus,
            ':prod_secobs' => $prod_sec_obs,
            ':prod_secobs_dia' => $prod_sec_obs_dia,
            ':prod_secobs_area' => $prod_sec_obs_area,
            ':prodcoat' => $prod_coat,
            ':prodmnt_type' => $prod_mnt_type,
            ':prodastro' => $prod_astro,
            ':prodcomp' => $prod_comp,
            ':prodmat_bear' => $prod_mat_bear,
            ':prodmat_mount' => $prod_mat_mount,
            ':prodtube_len' => $prod_tube_len,
            ':prodweight_tube' => $prod_weight_tube,
            ':prodweight_mnt' => $prod_weight_mnt,
            ':prodfeat' => $prod_feat,
            ':prodwarranty' => $prod_warranty
        );*/

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($queryparams);

        $rows = $result->fetchAll();

        exit;
    }

    else
    {
        $prod_id = $_GET['id'];
        if (strlen($prod_id) > 0)
        {
            $query = "
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM fin_prod WHERE prod_id=$prod_id
            ";

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':prod_id', $prod_id);
            $stmt->execute();

           /* $stmt->fetchAll();*/
            while($rows = $stmt->fetchAll())
            {
                $prod_model = $rows['prod_model'];
                $prod_desc = $rows['prod_desc'];
                $prod_price = $rows['prod_price'];
                $prod_vol = $rows['prod_vol'];
                $prod_img1 = $rows['prod_img1'];
                $prod_img1_desc = $rows['prod_img1_desc'];
                $prod_img2 = $rows['prod_img2'];
                $prod_img2_desc = $rows['prod_img2_desc'];
                $prod_img3 = $rows['prod_img3'];
                $prod_img3_desc = $rows['prod_img3_desc'];
                $prod_img4 = $rows['prod_img4'];
                $prod_img4_desc = $rows['prod_img4_desc'];
                $prod_img5 = $rows['prod_img5'];
                $prod_img5_desc = $rows['prod_img5_desc'];
                $prod_ulvl = $rows['prod_ulvl'];
                $prod_type = $rows['prod_type'];
                $prod_manu = $rows['prod_manu'];
                $prod_view = $rows['prod_view'];
                $prod_imaging = $rows['prod_imaging'];
                $prod_op_design = $rows['prod_op_design'];
                $prod_focal_len = $rows['prod_focal_len'];
                $prod_op_dia = $rows['prod_op_dia'];
                $prod_focal_ratio = $rows['prod_focal_ratio'];
                $prod_op_type = $rows['prod_op_type'];
                $prod_glass = $rows['prod_glass'];
                $prod_eye1 = $rows['prod_eye1'];
                $prod_eye1_mag = $rows['prod_eye1_mag'];
                $prod_eye2 = $rows['prod_eye2'];
                $prod_eye2_mag = $rows['prod_eye2_mag'];
                $prod_mag_low = $rows['prod_mag_low'];
                $prod_mag_high = $rows['prod_mag_high'];
                $prod_mag_theo = $rows['prod_mag_theo'];
                $prod_lim_stel = $rows['prod_lim_stel'];
                $prod_op_qual = $rows['prod_op_qual'];
                $prod_finder = $rows['prod_finder'];
                $prod_focus = $rows['prod_focus'];
                $prod_sec_obs = $rows['prod_sec_obs'];
                $prod_sec_obs_dia = $rows['prod_sec_obs_dia'];
                $prod_sec_obs_area = $rows['prod_sec_obs_area'];
                $prod_coat = $rows['prod_coat'];
                $prod_mnt_type = $rows['prod_mnt_type'];
                $prod_astro = $rows['prod_astro'];
                $prod_comp = $rows['prod_comp'];
                $prod_mat_bear = $rows['prod_mat_bear'];
                $prod_mat_mount = $rows['prod_mat_mount'];
                $prod_tube_len = $rows['prod_tube_len'];
                $prod_weight_tube = $rows['prod_weight_tube'];
                $prod_weight_mnt = $rows['prod_weight_mnt'];
                $prod_feat = $rows['prod_feat'];
                $prod_warranty = $rows['prod_warranty'];
            }
        }

        else
        {
            echo "Invalid Item ID";
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
<div class="product-edit-wrapper">
    <div class="edit-name">
        <h1>Edit Product &raquo; <?php echo $prod_model; ?></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include '../inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: so after 2 minutes of reading i figured out its just an typo what the hack ...

Comment: I apologize I have been on 22 hour days for the past week working on finishing up. The problem is when I call the $prod_id down in the h1 it does not appear at all. I forgot before posting the code to change the SELECT back to the :prod_id and that is my fault. Like I said, this has been a very long week.

Comment: you need to learn to separate matters. this incredible long code does several things. In have to isolate them from each other and work on the certain part only. and it turns out that the problem code was at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM fin_prod WHERE prod_id = :prod_id
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM fin_prod WHERE prod_id = $prod_id
```

See [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

---

Use [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `fetchAll()`.

Replace:

```
while($rows = $stmt->fetchAll())
```

With

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// or even $row for readability
// exclude bottom part from cycle
```

You will get 1 row (if searching by Primary Key) any way, so why the cycle?

Comment: I was following a tutorial I came across and what additional instruction I could get from the instructor.

Comment: That fixed and thank you Corrupt. I think I can finally see a bed in my future.

Comment: @NathanJ2012 Take a rest. "Tired pilot is worse than a drunk pilot".

Comment: haha I will keep that in mind, but there is no rest for the wicked and I have to finish by Thursday @6pm